# Difference in behaviour of a class when invoked in Platform Event Trigger vs Anonymous Apex

Tags: apex, trigger, platform-event

Hello SF StackExchange community,

I am currently encountering a strange behaviour with Platform Events Trigger and couldn't find an explanation. I am getting the "***attempt to de-reference a null object***" exception from a class method that is called from a trigger which is a consumer of a Platform Event, the same method was tested and was working perfectly fine when executed in anonymous apex or lwc controller by the same user which I checked using **UserInfo.getUserId**. I created a record for **PlatformEventSubscriberConfig** in order to run the trigger as a specific user.

My initial goal was to run this method as another user, because it relies on a 3rd party package and it was not working when invoked by customer community users but worked fine for internal users. I already opened a ticket with the custom support of the 3rd party package but they are usually slow to reply and I was hoping to fix it quickly by myself.

I didn't include any code sample as it is the same method that is invoked differently, but I can add details if required to clarify my question.

Any idea what would explain that so I can investigate further ?

Comment: the debug log for the running user when consuming the Platform Event should enable you to trace the issue.

Comment: I seem to recall a mention somewhere of needing to suspend the subscription to a PE and wait for a while before re-enabling it for a `PlatformEventSubscriberConfig` to actually take effect. Also, the last time I tried to test a PE with a `PlatformEventSubscriberConfig` (about a year ago) the test didn't honor the subscriber config.

Comment: Ah, found the bit about suspending in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_trigger_config.htm. __"If a trigger is running and subscribed to a platform event, new configuration settings take effect after you suspend and resume the trigger. You can suspend and resume a trigger from the platform event detail page by clicking Manage next to the Apex trigger in the Subscriptions related list."__

Comment: @cropredy I'm not able to trace the issue because it is coming from the managed package and couldn't get more details from the logs.

Comment: @derekF I already did that for changes to take effect, and I confirmed by printing UserInfo in the debug log.

Comment: Are you saying the exception happens in the 3rd party code rather than your own code?

Comment: It is worth remembering that anon apex runs in user mode, unlike normal apex which runs in system mode. Do you know whether the code is with or without sharing also, logs from managed package code do show SOQL and DML details and more can be gained via subscriber login by the third party's support or developer teams (so definitely worth asking for their help if they can).

Comment: @PhilW Yes the exception is coming from the 3rd party code. It's true that you can get some infos about SOQL and DML operations from the managed package logs, but all queries are returning results and I can't figure out why there is an exception since I am sure the same user that runs the same code in anon apex gets no exception but does when executed in a platform event trigger.
I opened a ticket with their support but they are too slow and asking me to repeat countless actions to go back to the same point where it started.

Comment: I personally would grant them subscriber access and invite them to capture full logs for their package - I am assuming this package has passed security review and therefore allows such subscriber logs to be captured...? You just need to work with them by coordinating their log capture with your execution of the two scenarios. They should then triage these logs to spot the difference and let you know the reason.

Comment: After few escalations with their support team a developer asked to be granted subscriber login access and he found that the profile was missing read access to one of the required objects. That object was missing their namespace that's why it was omitted from my permission set.
I found the reason of the exception but still cannot explain the strange behaviour of the trigger ?! it will probably remain a mystery for now.
Thank you all.